# When is blocking code acceptable in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I know that blocking code is discouraged in `node.js` because it is single-threaded. My question is asking whether or not blocking code is acceptable in certain circumstances.

For example, if I was running an [Express](http://expressjs.com/) webserver that requires a [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) connection, would it be acceptable to block the event loop until the database connection was established? This is assuming that all pages served by Express require a database query (which would fail if MongoDB was not initialized).

Another example would be an application that requires the contents of a configuration file before being initializing. Is there any benefit in using `fs.readFile` over `fs.readFileSync` in this case?

Is there a way to work around this? Is wrapping all the code in a callback or promise the best way to go? How would that be different from using blocking code in the above examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really up to you to decide what is acceptable.  And you would do that by determining what the consequences of blocking would be ... on a case-by-case basis.  That analysis would take into account:

- how often it occurs,
- how long the event loop is likely to be blocked, and
- the impact that blocking *in that context* will have on usability<sup>1</sup>.

Obviously, there are ways to avoid blocking, but these tend to add complexity to your application.  Really, you need to decide ... on a case-by-case basis ... whether that added complexity is warranted.

Bottom line: >>you<< need to decide what is acceptable based on your understanding of your application and your users.

---

<sup>1 - For example, in a game it would be more acceptable to block the UI while switching "levels" than during active play.  Or for a general web service, "once off" blocking while a config file is loaded or a DB connection is established *during webserver startup* is more acceptable that if this happened on every request.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This was what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience most tasks should be handled in a callback or by returning a promise. You DO NOT want to block code in a Node application. That's what makes it so nice! Mostly with MongoDB it will crash before it has a chance to connect if there is no connection. It won't' really have an effect on an API call because your server will be dead!

Source: I'm a developer at a bootcamp that teaches MEAN stack.

Answer (score -1):

Your two examples are completely different. The distinction actually answers the question in and of itself.

Grabbing data from a database is dependent on being connected to that database. Any code that is dependent upon that data is then dependent upon that connection. These things have to happen serially for the app to function and be meaningful.

On the other hand, readFileSync will block ALL code, not just code that is reliant on it. You could start reading a csv file while simultaneously establishing a database connection. Once both are done, you could add that csv data to the database.

Comment: The examples given are completely separate examples. In both examples, the assumption is that the rest of the application is reliant upon the results of either the database connection or reading the file.

Comment: That's my point. It needs to be blocking if there are dependencies. That has nothing to do with language-specific design patterns. In regards to your comment, readFile and readFileSync do the exact same thing in relation to the rest of your application. This has nothing to do with language design patterns. This is basic control flow applicable to every language.